# Pytesseract doesnt recognize simple text in image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to recognize a image like this:

[image]

I am using the following config:

```
config="--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,."
```

but when I try to convert that, I get the following:

> 1581

> 1

> W

I think that the image shows really clearly what is written and think that there is a problem with pytesseract. Can you help?

Comment: it also happened for me, one time it showed me a star as a dot, while there are so many stars in the same image, don't know whats wrong... but i didn't use any configs

Comment: @GhostOps Yes but with such a clean image this must be possible right?

Comment: yeah, dont know whats wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessing the image to obtain a binary image before performing OCR seems to work. You could also try to resize the image so that more details would be seen

[image]

Results

```
158.1
1
IT
```

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Grayscale and Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Perform text extraction
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I resized it and now it works flawless